# GTKSocket, widget, and glade

Tags: gtk, pygtk, glade

I have the following code:

```
    builder = gtk.Builder()
    builder.add_from_file(glade_file)
    builder.get_object("windowMain").show()
    socket = gtk.Socket()
    socket.add_id(long(OpenGLWindowID))
    builder.get_object('alignment1').add(socket)
```

where alignment1 is a GtkAlignment widget.  But when I run this, I get:

```
fubar.py:64: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_socket_add_id: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (socket)' failed
  socket.add_id(long(self.OpenGLWindowID))
```

Does anyone know which widget I should use Gtk.Socket() with when building the glade file?  Have I mis-understood something vital?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add the socket to the alignment *before* you call the `add_id()` method.